# Redux-Form separating displayed value and submitted value in custom component

Tags: reactjs, normalization, redux-form

I have a custom component CurrencyBox and I use redux-form to submit and validate form. It works perfectly for entered inputs like "123,345", "1.000.000", or "9.000,123" etc.

Today, I need to send input value (1.000.000,456) to server as (1000000,456).

**In short**, displayed value must be like **123.456,789**  but submitted value must be **123456,789**

Is there anyway to handle this?

I checked normalizers etc. but these are not feasible solutions for me. I just want to separate displayed value and submitted value.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a wrapper component for the input component, for example TextField, this component should receive the mask and the actual value, you will need to setup a few handlers for `onChange`, `onFocus` and any other callback that you need, for example:

```
const { string, func } = PropTypes;

class TextField extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    value: string,
    onChange: func,
    format: string,
  };

  getFormat(value) {
    // set the format that you need
    // based on the format prop or any other option
    return applyFormat(value);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const { onChange } = this.props;

    if (onChange) {
      // Before returning the value
      // you need to remove the format
      onChange(removeFormat(value));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;

    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.getFormat(value)}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This is a very simple example of what you could do, basically before rendering the value you set the format and on the `onChange` you need to remove the format, you could implement the `onBlur` instead of the `onChange`, this way if you are using redux the data will be send to your reducer until the user completes the editing, preventing calling the reducer on every keystroke.

Usage:

```
<TextField
 value={this.props.dataFromRedux}
 onChange={this.props.actionCreatorToSaveValueOnState}
/>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'am trying likely solution. I will reply to you. In Addition, I like your answer.